# python JSON feed returns string not object

Tags: python, json

I can import this json feed with this code

```
import json
import requests
url = 'http://espn.go.com/sports/scores/feed?sportId=28&eventId=0&rand=1410039271798&xhr=1'
r = requests.get(url)
pbpObj = json.loads(r.content)
```

but when I try to load this JSON feed I get the following error

'http://data.ncaa.com/jsonp/scoreboard/football/fbs/2014/03/scoreboard.html?callback=ncaaScoreboard.dispScoreboard'

```
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-499-a086c9c2c95f> in <module>()
      3 url = 'http://data.ncaa.com/jsonp/scoreboard/football/fbs/2014/03/scoreboard.html?callback=ncaaScoreboard.dispScoreboard'
      4 r = requests.get(url)
----> 5 pbpObj = json.loads(r.content)

C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.pyc in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    336             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    337             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 338         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    339     if cls is None:
    340         cls = JSONDecoder

C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.pyc in decode(self, s, _w)
    363 
    364         """
--> 365         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    366         end = _w(s, end).end()
    367         if end != len(s):

C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.pyc in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    381             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    382         except StopIteration:
--> 383             raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
    384         return obj, end

ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Comment: OK pbpObj = r.content works  Thank you

Comment: But that's not decoded JSON. I was asking you to show what is *in* `r.content`. What did the server return to you that is not JSON? And what is `r.status_code`?

Comment: OK sorry r.status_code is 200   r.content returns a string that looks just like it does if you put the url into a browser

Comment: Can you put that into your question? That's unexpected behaviour; do you have a proxy of some kind? A URL is not JSON, in any case.

Comment: OK changed the title i am not using a  proxy

Comment: Right, I misunderstood your question; I did not realise you had the first part working, but that the other URL didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to load **JSONP** data, not JSON data. [JSONP (JSON with Padding)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) wraps the JSON data in a callback.

I could not find a JSON-only version of the same API; you'll have to unwrap the callback yourself first. Use a short callback name of known length to make this easier for yourself:

```
url = 'http://data.ncaa.com/jsonp/scoreboard/football/fbs/2014/03/scoreboard.html?callback=c'
r = requests.get(url)
pbpObj = json.loads(r.content[2:-2])
```

The string slice removes the `c(...);` callback code from the start and end of the response.