# trouble scraping from JSONP feed

Tags: python, json, jsonp

I asked a similar question earlier

[python JSON feed returns string not object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25828611/python-json-feed-returns-string-not-object)

but I am having a little more trouble and don't understand it.

For about half of the dates this works and returns a JSON object

for example November 9 2013 works

```
url = 'http://data.ncaa.com/jsonp/scoreboard/basketball-men/d1/2013/11/09/scoreboard.html?callback=c'
r = requests.get(url)
jsonObj = json.loads(r.content[2:-2])
```

but if I try November 11 2013:

```
url = 'http://data.ncaa.com/jsonp/scoreboard/basketball-men/d1/2013/11/11/scoreboard.html?callback=c'
r = requests.get(url)
jsonObj = json.loads(r.content[2:-2])
```

I get this error

**ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded**

I dont understand why.  When I put both urls into a browser they look exactly the same.

Comment: Is the url valid for 2019?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using demjson

```
demjson.decode(r.content[2:-2])
```

seems to work

Answer (score 1):

The JSON in the second feed is, in fact, invalid JSON. Found this by removing the callback function and running it through: http://jsonlint.com/

To see for yourself, search for the following ID: `336252`

The lines just above that ID contain two commas in a row, which is disallowed by the JSON spec.

My guess is that the server at data.ncaa.com is trying to generate JSON itself rather than using a JSON library. You should contact the site administrator and make them aware of this error.